How is payment api gateway interfaced if I have 2 or more regions using different gateways?
I am currently designing an app for 2 different regions, 1 in US and 1 in Taiwan.
For US, I am using Stripe as the payment gateway api,
For Taiwan I am using Newebpay as Stripe is not available.
These 2 API payment gateways shall allow users to add credit card details as a form of payment transaction.
In the UI itself should I have a country dropdown selection and then show credit card detail entry form, or is there a way where mobile device is able to detect where the user is located and display this entry form accordingly?
I won't be allowing GPS due to privacy concerns.

Once the user enters the billing address, the location will be revealed.

IP address? Or is it a mobile app?

Are you able to link Country to the account?. If your user signs-up you can add Country as a required field, and then with that you can set the right payment method.

If you have the ability to add Country to the user's account then you can use get rid of the Country field in the application, however if for some reason your user needs to change the country to make a payment then you should be able to link it and use the payment method. There are some accounts like Alexa or Amazon that allows you switch accounts to different countries but you need to use another email. That resides on your application architecture.



You may have 2 cards showing the flags and name of each country. That will help users choose their preferred means of payment.
